# How to extract text and username from json returned by twitter?

Tags: java, json, twitter

I want to extract only username and text from JSON data returned by Twitter. I tried JSON parser but I am unable to solve.

I am using Twitter's HBC API to retrieve user tweets. However, this is returning JSON data. I've been searching through Twitter's API to find a way to ONLY pull tweets text and username instead of the whole JSON but can not find a good solution. Could anyone lend a hand?

```
package abc;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.twitter.hbc.ClientBuilder;
import com.twitter.hbc.core.Client;
import com.twitter.hbc.core.Constants;
import com.twitter.hbc.core.Hosts;
import com.twitter.hbc.core.HttpHosts;
import com.twitter.hbc.core.endpoint.StatusesFilterEndpoint;
import com.twitter.hbc.core.processor.StringDelimitedProcessor;
import com.twitter.hbc.httpclient.auth.Authentication;
import com.twitter.hbc.httpclient.auth.OAuth1;
import twitter4j.internal.org.json.JSONException;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.*;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TwitterProducer {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TwitterProducer.class.getName());

    // use your own credentials - don't share them with anyone
    String consumerKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    String consumerSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    String token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    String secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    List<String> terms = Lists.newArrayList("india");


    public TwitterProducer(){}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new TwitterProducer().run();
    }

    public void run() throws Exception{

        logger.info("Setup");

        /** Set up your blocking queues: Be sure to size these properly based on expected TPS of your stream */
        BlockingQueue<String> msgQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>(1000);

        // create a twitter client
        Client client = createTwitterClient(msgQueue);
        // Attempts to establish a connection.
        client.connect();
       // create a kafka producer
        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = createKafkaProducer();

        // add a shutdown hook
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
            logger.info("stopping application...");
            logger.info("shutting down client from twitter...");
            client.stop();
            logger.info("closing producer...");
            producer.close();
            logger.info("done!");
        }));

        // loop to send tweets to kafka
        // on a different thread, or multiple different threads....
        while (!client.isDone()) {
            String msg = null;
            try {
                msg = msgQueue.poll(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                client.stop();
            }

            if (msg != null){
                logger.info(msg);
                producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("course5i", null, msg), new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata recordMetadata, Exception e) {
                        if (e != null) {
                            logger.error("Something bad happened", e);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        logger.info("End of application");
    }

    public Client createTwitterClient(BlockingQueue<String> msgQueue){

       /** Declare the host you want to connect to, the endpoint, and authentication (basic auth or oauth) */
        Hosts hosebirdHosts = new HttpHosts(Constants.STREAM_HOST);
        StatusesFilterEndpoint hosebirdEndpoint = new StatusesFilterEndpoint();

        hosebirdEndpoint.trackTerms(terms);

        // These secrets should be read from a config file
        Authentication hosebirdAuth = new OAuth1(consumerKey, consumerSecret, token, secret);

        ClientBuilder builder = new ClientBuilder()
                .name("Hosebird-Client-01")                              // optional: mainly for the logs
                .hosts(hosebirdHosts)
                .authentication(hosebirdAuth)
                .endpoint(hosebirdEndpoint)
                .processor(new StringDelimitedProcessor(msgQueue));

               Client hosebirdClient = builder.build();
               return hosebirdClient;
    }

    public KafkaProducer<String, String> createKafkaProducer(){
        String bootstrapServers = "127.0.0.1:9092";

        // create Producer properties
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());

        // create safe Producer
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, "true");
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, Integer.toString(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION, "5"); // kafka 2.0 >= 1.1 so we can keep this as 5. Use 1 otherwise.

        // high throughput producer (at the expense of a bit of latency and CPU usage)
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "snappy");
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, "20");
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, Integer.toString(32*1024)); // 32 KB batch size

        // create the producer
        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);
        return producer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add how that json response from twitter looks like

Comment: I don't see any code which tries to parse the json here. Could you be more specific? Where do you try to extract "username" and "text"?

Comment: @BugsForBreakfast{"created_at":"Sun Aug 11 18:02:05 +0000 2019",
"id":1160612366238642176,
"id_str":"1160612366238642176",
"text":"hi how are you",
"source":"\u003ca href=\"https:\/\/mobile.twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web App\u003c\/a\u003e",
"truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,
"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null}

Comment: @SergeiSirik i tried it in run() after blocnking queue

Comment: @Arun okay, are you storing that json as a string on any variable? if not, store it first on a variable so we can work it, I don't know if you can only request username and tweet text, but if you can't then what you can do is get only those attributes from the json, you know how to do this?

Comment: @BugsForBreakfast i dont know how to parse that json to string but that msgQueue contaion whole json.  BlockingQueue<String> msgQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>(1000);

Comment: @Arun so you have to use that string to make a json object, and after that you can access its properties, I will post an answer as a example

Comment: @Arun get the json out from that msgQueue and instantiate an String with its value, check the answer I posted for you

Answer (score 1):

Create a class with the attributes name exactly as what is in the json response along with getters/setters. 
Use Jackson ObjectMapper's readValue() function to map those values to a object of that class.

Refer to this: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JSONObject from any library, but I recommend you to use PrimeFaces one because its very simple, so you need to do something like so:

```
import org.primefaces.json.JSONObject;

String yourJsonString = msgQueue // Here you need to get your json from that msgQueue and save it as a String, or pass it directly to the argument of following JSONObject
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(yourJsonString);
// After you have the object created you can just access and store the fields you need like so:
// Im not sure if by username you ment the id but I can't see a field username on the json
String userName = jsonObject.getString("id");
String text = jsonObject.getString("text");
```

and that should be it, then you can use those object for what you need